# Wallpaper isn't full screen on Ubuntu in VMware

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-workstation

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 in VMware Workstation on Windows 8.1. Each time I log on, the wallpaper only covers the top left of the screen (please see the screenshot). To resolve the issue, I swap the wallpaper back and forth from another. But small things like this rather annoy me. Can anybody suggest a permanent fix?

**EDIT:** It's VMware version 11.1.2

[image]

Comment: Could I ask if you're running the latest version of VMware Workstation?

Comment: Yes, my mistake: 11.1.2